# Android - Derive the parent node of a child node using JSOUP

Tags: android, html, html-parsing, jsoup

I have to change the html code of a web page before showing it on my Android App. This is my situation:

```
<html>
    <div class="something">
         <a class="inner_something">
             <span class="title">Titolo1</span>
         </a>
    </div>

    <div class="something">
          <a class="inner_something">
             <span class="title">Titolo2</span>
         </a>
    </div>
</html>
```

I want to remove the `div` that contains within it the `span` that contains the text= Titolo2. How i can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with Jsoup:

```
String html = "<html>\n"
            + "    <div class=\"something\">\n"
            + "         <a class=\"inner_something\">\n"
            + "             <span class=\"title\">Titolo1</span>\n"
            + "         </a>\n"
            + "    </div>\n"
            + "\n"
            + "    <div class=\"something\">\n"
            + "          <a class=\"inner_something\">\n"
            + "             <span class=\"title\">Titolo2</span>\n"
            + "         </a>\n"
            + "    </div>\n"
            + "</html>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
doc.select("div:has(a:has(span:contains(Titolo2)))").first().remove();

System.out.println(doc);
```

To load the processed HTML Document into your `WebView`, do:

```
 myWebView.loadData(doc.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

You can also [tweak the selector](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) (`doc.select("div.something");`) to select and remove exactly what you want.

In your case, it's a little tricky: you have to select based on the content, so use `:contains(text)`.

---

To count the number of `div`s with a certain class, do something like this:

```
Elements divs = doc.select("div.someclass");
int count = divs.size();
```

Will give you the count of divs with class `someclass`.

Comment: Ok it is functioning, but the situation is much more complicated.... It is possible instead count the number of div that belong to the same class?